# What is the cleanest/correct way to handle Future.get() custom exceptions inside callable? (Advanced)

Tags: java, exception

Code:

```
  public void processData(PaymentRequest data) {
    List<Payment> paymentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Callable<Payment>> paymentCallables = new ArrayList<>();

    data.getPaymentInfoList().forEach(payment -> paymentCallables.add(() -> payment.execute()));

    try {
      executorService.invokeAll(paymentCallables)
              .stream()
              .map(this::apply)
              .forEach(paymentList::add);
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
      throw new ProcessorException("task interrupted when processing", exception);
    }
  }

  private Payment apply(Future<Payment> paymentFuture) {
    try {
      return paymentFuture.get(); //Only shows ExecutuonException
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException exception) {
      throw new ProcessorException("task interrupted or failed", exception);
    }
  }
```

I have omitted some code for clarity.

**BACKGROUND INFO**

My system has a list of callables. In this list, there are some executions that will execute at a later date. **The key thing to note is that the executions that will run have custom exceptions inside them.**

When the code is run, and there is an exception in one of the callable executions. An exception is thrown; **Specifically, this exception happens at paymentFuture.get().**

**THE PROBLEM**

I have my own custom exceptions in payment.execute(). For example, I have a validation exception inside payments.execute() method. Example:

```
public void execute() {
try {
//process
} catch (
throw new ValidationException();
}
```

**THE PROBLEM IS** when this exception occurs, and ValidationException is thrown, this exception gets wrapped up by ExecutionException. So what is being handled is ExecutionException. So java wraps ExecutionException around my ValidationExecption. What I want is for a way to handle and throw ValidationException out of the class so it can be handled by another class GlobalExceptionHandler.

PS:
Doing:

```
throw exception.getCause()
```

Will not work because exceptions NEED to be handled with try/catch in the method and I would like to throw a new exception that can be caught by an external class.

Been trying to sort this out for hours so Im open for all ideas.

Comment: could you elaborate on "Will not work because exceptions NEED to be handled with try/catch in the method"? is `ValidationException` a checked exception, so you can't re-throw it without modifying the method `throws` list?

Comment: ValidationException is not a checked exception. This is just a custom exception I need in my system. What I meant with that statement is that due to Java 8 stream, exceptions have to be handled with try/catch and can't be thrown and delegated to another class/method.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you catch the execution exception, check it's cause's type, and throw your own exception for validation failure? You probably need to post the code as you want it to be.

Comment: @daniu That means for every exception that I have in the execute() method, that will require it's own if statement. I don't think that's the cleanest way to approach the problem

Comment: @daniu, yes, that's my initial suggestion as well, and I don't understand why it won't be working

Comment: For example, I have around 6 different custom exceptions in the execute() method. Do you propose that there needs to be an if statement for each exception?

Comment: If that is not what you mean, please provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the exceptions that may be thrown from the `payment.execute` method can be grouped by a common interface, let's say `PaymentException`.

`ValidationException` would extend `PaymentException`.

In this case, you would need to check `exception.getCause() instanceof PaymentException` and rethrow the cause if the condition is `true`.

```
try {
    return paymentFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException exception) {
    final Throwable cause = exception.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof PaymentException) {
       throw (PaymentException) cause;
    }
    throw new ProcessorException("task interrupted or failed", exception);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Because throwing 'cause' requires Throwable exception to be handled.

Comment: And also, is this approach good from a design perspective? That would mean every exception in my execute() method will have to extend PaymentException. Don't you think that could be a problem if this scales up to many more exceptions?

Comment: @bob9123 corrected to `throw (PaymentException) cause`

Comment: @bob9123 you aren't supposed to make every exception extend `PaymentException`, you can build a pretty multilevel hierarchy of exceptions.

Comment: @bob9123 btw, throwing 10 different exceptions from a single method sounds like a bad design. It might mean that the method takes too much responsibility.

Comment: It's not just a single method that executes in my service when execute() is called. I delegate the execution to other classes. My point is, I feel there could be a coupling problem that may arise as everything that happens in execute in regards to exceptions has to be in that catch instanceof. I may be wrong though. What do you think.

Comment: @bob9123 I don't get why there could be a coupling problem. We refer to a parent class to define a specific behaviour for all its subclasses. Of course, a class shouldn't extend `PaymentException` only for the reason to be rethrown.